# C# WPF Web Browser Control Security Error

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf

I'm currently having trouble to nagivate to local file which have the index.html.

I had try to copied the URL link to firefox and google chrome and it worked. But when I'm trying to navigate to the URL link with C# Web Browser Control, it gave me a black screen with

> Fatal: loading error (Security Error)

which I feel very weird.

Here is the example link: `file://127.0.0.1/c$/Users/Marcus/Desktop/03%20Virtual%20Tour/dataranlang/index.html`

Here is my code that used to called for the URL link in C# Web Browser Control:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Perak360
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.WB.Loaded += (s, e) =>
            {
                // get the underlying WebBrowser ActiveX object;
                // this code depends on SHDocVw.dll COM interop assembly,
                // generate SHDocVw.dll: "tlbimp.exe ieframe.dll",
                // and add as a reference to the project

                var activeX = this.WB.GetType().InvokeMember("ActiveXInstance",
                    BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                    null, this.WB, new object[] { }) as SHDocVw.WebBrowser;

                // now we can handle previously inaccessible WB events 
                activeX.FileDownload += activeX_FileDownload;
            };

            this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    this.WB.Source = new Uri(new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\Users\Marcus Tan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Perak360\Perak360\Perakin360 Offline (Final)\index.html").FullName);
                    //this.WB.Navigate(Properties.Settings.Default.WebBrowserPath);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            };


        }

        void activeX_FileDownload(bool ActiveDocument, ref bool Cancel)
        {
            Cancel = true;
        }

        private void CloseWindow(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }

    }
}
```

I know that if i changed the URL link to `file://C:/Users/Marcus%20Tan/Desktop/03%20Virtual%20Tour/dataranlang/index.html` it may work, but there will be a javascript prompt out which ask user to enable the blocked content which I don't want it to be appear.

Any clue what wrong with my URL link or code which it gave me a black screen without the loading error screen? I had try to search online for solution and try to set the Internet Security setting, but none of it work.

Please guide me through this.

Comment: did you try with any live link I think because of file tag WPF browser not able to render the content of html file why don't you try with any live link and check if it's working or not

Comment: @dhaval patel i had try with other link and it work for the other link

Comment: yes that means if you want to open that html in your wpf browser then you have to host that page in local iis and use it

Comment: @DhavalPatel you sure the security error is the cause that i don't host the page in my local iis?

Comment: you can try may be it's work

Comment: @DhavalPatel I hosted in with xampp and it seem to work now

Comment: Great :)............................